# Git merge then hard reset wiped previous branch that was being merged

Tags: git, merge

I have 2 branches, one called feature and another called feature-merge. I was trying to merge feature-merge into feature but during the merge I wanted to change something in feature-merge before merging. I had already resolved a few merge conflicts and staged everything, including the assets I had lost (since I was merging from an asset directory to a non-asset directory) so

```
git merge --abort
```

didn't work.

I looked online and there were people saying to use

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

which I did. After that was done, I switched back to feature-merge and it was completely different from the previous commit. A lot of stuff was deleted, mainly asset files and folders. I'm honestly not sure what happened. I've tried using

```
git reflog
git checkout <commit hash>
```

but that also doesn't work. Even when going back to the last commit of feature-merge, where I know I committed all the asset files, they are still gone. Doing

```
git fsck --lost-found
```

There are a ton of object files so I'm sure it's there.

Comment: What’s the question?

Comment: @matt Oh sorry, just if there is a way to retrieve the lost commit. And it would also be nice to understand what happened because I'm not sure.

Comment: No commit is ever lost, changed, or deleted. (Unless they are orphaned and pruned.) Every file version you have ever committed is still present and retrievable.  If you can find, using reflog or whatever, the commit that held the state of things before you did whatever you did, then I assure you that it still contains all of its files. If checkout seems to be missing files, then those files were never added to that commit in the first place; you must have been telling git to ignore them.